# Tanh expansion problem

Tags: trigonometry, taylor-expansion

$$\frac{exp(-\beta e_k) - exp(\beta e_k)}{exp(-\beta e_k) + exp(\beta e_k)} = tanh(-\beta e_k)$$

In the context of mean field annealing I reached this equation but I am not sure how to expand tanh to get to this equation.

Answer (score 2):

By definition,
\begin{align}
\tanh x &= \frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x} \\
        &= \frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}
\end{align}

In your case
\begin{align}
\tanh (-x)  &= \frac{e^{-x}-e^{x}}{e^{-x}+e^{x}}
\end{align}
Where $x=\beta e_k$

Further note that since $\tanh (-x) = -\tanh x$ your relation involving $\beta e_k$ could be re-written in a simpler form.